# HTML/CSS paragraphs and div

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a problem with my div and the paragraph there's inside
The thing I want to do is with the div having an animation for the width (going from 0% to 80% in 2s) and the only problem I have is that inside the div there's the paragraph with some sentences written within; that causes the div to be too big in horizontal (it does have a background color, but I have to change it with an image).

So, How can I solve the problem of the paragraph being there but something like invisible and not occupying space (then it has to appear at some time)?

Edit:

```
div.pick
{
height:30%;
overflow:hidden;
animation: example 2s;
}
@keyframes example
{
0%
{
width:0%;
}
100%
{
width:80%;
}
```

So basically this is the code for the div and inside there's an image (that's not the issue)
The issue is that the paragraph written expand horizzontally, and i don't want that. I want the paragraph to be always to the right of the image and not expanding horizzontally, is there a way?

I thought of something like making the text going out of the div with opacity 0 and when the div expanded to the max making it appear, I wanted to know if there was another way

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you haven't used the site before please read the FAQs but we need to see code or what you tried first please.

Comment: Please provide code or screenshot something like that

Comment: Did you try? Did you fail? Share some code if so, or otherwise, a screenshot /  image explaining what are you trying to achieve

Comment: By animation, you mean CSS3 animations or javascript animations?

Comment: Code please, How could we guess your code? People in stackoverflow are not god.

Comment: I suspect that you are looking for overflow: hidden on the animated div and a fixed width on the paragraphs inside, assuming I've understood your question correctly?

Comment: I added the code for the div, sorry for being late

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language.  Please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have an answer to your question, the below should work for what you would like to achieve.

You can set a fixed width to your container element so the text does not exceed this. If you set the opacity of your text to 0 and change this to 1 when your animation is complete that will reveal the text gradually to your entered animation time.

```
            <style>

            .box { width:200px; height:100%; border:1px solid red; }
            .box p { opacity:0; }
            .box:hover { animation:expandDiv 2s linear forwards; -webkit-animation:expandDiv 2s linear forwards; }
            .box:hover p { animation:revealText 2s linear forwards; -webkit-animation:revealText 2s linear forwards; }

            @keyframes expandDiv { 
                100% { width:300px; }   
            }   

            @-webkit-keyframes expandDiv { 
                100% { width:300px; }   
            }

            @keyframes revealText {
                100% { opacity:1; }     
            }   

            @-webkit-keyframes revealText { 
                100% { opacity:1; } 
            }

            </style>    


            <div class="box">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
            </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How are you able to guess this is the write answer without any code?

Comment: I think I understand the question but I may be wrong @SaugatBhattarai